How can I create a Power Automate Flow to compare data from two workbooks, including multiple sheets and columns?
I'm currently working on a process automation task involving Power Automate and Office Scripts in Excel. Here's the scenario:
When a new file is placed in a SharePoint folder, I want to trigger a Power Automate flow.
The flow should read a file named 'Input Requirements.xlsx' to get the defined worksheets and columns.
Subsequently, an Office Script needs to be executed to check whether the new file complies with the columns and worksheets specified in 'Input Requirements.xlsx'.
Finally, the script should return any missing worksheets and/or columns in the new file.
Input Requirements.xlsx

The sheet names and column names may vary dynamically.
The worksheet names and column names in the sample upload workbook should be validated against the table in "Input Requirements.xlsx" which lists valid worksheet and column names.

I've been exploring Power Automate and Office Scripts individually, but I'm having trouble integrating them to achieve this workflow efficiently. Specifically, I'm unsure about how to pass the requirements from 'Input Requirements.xlsx' to the Office Script and then retrieve the results back to Power Automate.
Here is the office script I have tried. I need to pass JSON to the office scripts.
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, requirementsJson: string): string {
// Parse the JSON string into an object
const requirements = JSON.parse(requirementsJson);
let errors: string[] = [];

// Loop through each worksheet requirement
for (const sheetRequirement of requirements.worksheets) {
    let sheet = workbook.getWorksheet(sheetRequirement.name);
    if (!sheet) {
        errors.push(`Missing worksheet: ${sheetRequirement.name}`);
        continue; // Skip to next worksheet requirement since this one is missing
    }

    // Check each column requirement in the worksheet
    for (const columnRequirement of sheetRequirement.columns) {
        let range = sheet.getRange(columnRequirement + "1");
        let values = range.getValues();

        // Check if the column is present
        if (!values || values[0][0] !== columnRequirement) {
            errors.push(`Missing column: ${columnRequirement} in worksheet: ${sheetRequirement.name}`);
        }
    }
}

// Return all collected errors, or a success message if no errors were found
if (errors.length > 0) {
    return "Errors found: \n" + errors.join("\n");
} else {
    return "File structure is correct.";
}

}
Here is the Power Automate Flow with the Compose 2 action: the JSON should ideally be dynamic, but for testing purposes, I've hardcoded the values.

I want to automate this task using either Power Automate or a combination of Power Automate and Office Scripts, keeping it simple.

Hi @Kavinda_404 - your flow seems like it should work, provided you replace the hardcoded JSON with the actual output of the "List rows present in table" action. Is it failing at a particular step? If so, could you share the error message? That will help us troubleshoot the issue.
